# Any free XHTML CSS editor with live(on type) W3C validation?

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I know W3C Validator can do this but i need any free offline editor.

I would like to see live error in IDE if i'm not closing any tag mistakenly like this http://livevalidation.com/ not after coding whole document.

if anything is not proper in xhtml and css then ID should show error on that place in source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSE HTML Validator Lite - FREE HTML Editor and HTML Checker for Windows [validator](http://www.freehtmlvalidator.com/)

and another by using firefox addon which can be downloaded from [mozilla site](https://addons.mozilla.org/addon/249)

Answer (score 2):

Use

**[HTML Tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/)**

> HTML Tidy is an open source program
>   and library for checking and
>   generating clean XHTML/HTML

Answer (score 0):

Emacs + flymake + tidy.
http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FlyMake#toc18